# Automation Server can't create object in IE8 after including condition for chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, applet, activexobject

Previously i was doing

```
    <script>
    function fun1(){
       var sh=new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
       sh.run("\\\\ntbot\\my.exe");
    }
    fun();
    </script>
```

there is no problem with this code. it happily execute exe on client machine from IE, to run same from chrome i written applet, and from that i am runing exe. so code changes i done are

```
<scipt>
    function testCSS(prop) {
        return prop in document.documentElement.style;
    }
     var isChrome = !!(window.chrome && chrome.webstore && chrome.webstore.install);
     var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || testCSS('msTransform'); 


        function fun2(isIE,isChrome)
        {
            if(isIE){
                var sh=new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
                sh.Run("\\\\ntbot\\my.exe");
                }if(isChrome){
                appletsource="<APPLET archive='CalciApplet.jar' codebase='/kiss' CODE='AppletGchrome.CalculateApplet.class' WIDTH='0' HEIGHT='0'></APPLET>"
                document.getElementById("appletplace").innerHTML=appletsource;
            }
        }

        fun2(isIE,isChrome);
</script>
```

not its working on Chrome, but not in IE in IE i am getting **Automation Server can't create object.** error

plz help me in this.. thank you.

Regards,
swapnil P.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is IE ***Only!*** It will never work on Chrome.

*Automation Server can't create object* means the security settings for activeX are set at the wrong level. Add your page to trusted sites.

Comment: yes, thats why i used signed applet for chrome. but code is working for ie and chrome on linux server. not on my local server. and also i dont have rights to change security settings :(

Comment: Well only way to make it run is to change settings. Have fun with a locked down machine.